# NUnit error: "FrameworkName cannot have less than two components or more than three components"

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, resharper

I am using:

- Visual Studio 2017 v15.5.4
- NUnit 3.9.0
- NUnit Test Adapter 3.9.0
- Resharper 2017.3
- .Net 4.7 project

I get random exceptions when trying to debug NUnit tests:

First is:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' : 'The assembly with
>   display name 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.VideoRecorderEngine'
>   failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID
>   1. The cause of the failure was: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.VideoRecorderEngine' or one of
>   its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly
>   manifest.'

Followed by:

> System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.VideoRecorderEngine' or one of
>   its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly
>   manifest.'

and:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' : 'The assembly with
>   display name 'VSTestVideoRecorder' failed to load in the 'Load'
>   binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The cause of the failure
>   was: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'VSTestVideoRecorder' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made
>   to load a program with an incorrect format.'

After some continues relevant exceptions appear:

> **Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoadFromContext' : 'The assembly named
>   'nunit.engine.api' was loaded from
>   'file:///C:/Users/[Username]/AppData/Local/Temp/VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions/NUnit3TestAdapter.3.9.0/build/net35/nunit.engine.api.DLL'
>   using the LoadFrom context. The use of this context can result in
>   unexpected behavior for serialization, casting and dependency
>   resolution. In almost all cases, it is recommended that the LoadFrom
>   context be avoided. This can be done by installing assemblies in the
>   Global Assembly Cache or in the ApplicationBase directory and using
>   Assembly.Load when explicitly loading assemblies.'**

and

> **Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoadFromContext' : 'The assembly named
>   'Mono.Cecil' was loaded from
>   'file:///C:/Users/[Username]/AppData/Local/Temp/VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions/NUnit3TestAdapter.3.9.0/build/net35/Mono.Cecil.DLL'
>   using the LoadFrom context. The use of this context can result in
>   unexpected behavior for serialization, casting and dependency
>   resolution. In almost all cases, it is recommended that the LoadFrom
>   context be avoided. This can be done by installing assemblies in the
>   Global Assembly Cache or in the ApplicationBase directory and using
>   Assembly.Load when explicitly loading assemblies.'**

At last:

> System.ArgumentException: 'FrameworkName cannot have less than two
>   components or more than three components. Parameter name:
>   frameworkName'

After that I can debug my tests, but there is new random exceptions
 when I pass a collection in debug view:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   collection'

With Stracktrace:

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument
>   argument)    at
>   **System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView`1..ctor(ICollection`1
>   collection)**

Comment: As far as I am concerned the `Managed Debugging Assistant` can be ignored. So the real problems are only the last 3 exceptions I posted

Answer (score 0):

Go to Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture. Ensure this matches your current system architecture, i.e. if your machine is 64 bit set this to X64 or vice versa:

[image]

Comment: did not work for me.
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=FrameworkName cannot have less than two components or more than three components.
Parameter name: frameworkName
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName..ctor(String frameworkName)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is a bug. [Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/224359/systemargumentexception-frameworkname-cannot-have.html) it is said that this will be fixed in VS 15.8 preview 3.

Answer (score 0):

I was still having this problem with version 15.9.11.  The [following workaround from the bug thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/232896/view.html) worked for me:

> 1. Explicitly enable the Break when Thrown the ArgumentException in the Exception Settings window
> 2. Debug the unit test and wait until debugger breaks due to the FrameworkName (because it is an ArgumentException).
> 3. Use the Exception Thrown window in the debugger and check set the "Except when thrown from: System.dll" So, we are telling the debugger
>      to ignore the ArgumentException when thrown inside the System.dll.
>
> [image: Exception popup]